# Download Pdf file from local machine to display it in browser using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am unable to download the pdf of my local machine to browser. I am using $.ajax(),in this ajax call i am calling the web api and this web api will download the PDF to the local machine and then on wards I need to get the download pop up to download that generated PDF.

How Can we achieve this one?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: where is pdf file stored ? ''download the pdf of my local machine to browser'' ??

Comment: It is stored in my local machine C drive